# Input array length is longer than the number of columns in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I created a windows form with a datagridview. I have created the following code to create the table and load the user input. I keep getting error input array is longer than the number of columns. Not sure how? as I have set the columns build.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp17
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        private void Add_Row_To_DataGridView_Using_TextBoxes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // set datatable columns values
            DataTable Test = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));// data type int
            table.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));// datatype string
            table.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));// datatype string
            table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));// data type int

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(textBoxID.Text, textBoxFN.Text, textBoxLN.Text, textBoxAGE.Text);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get this array (wich line)? Also please provide the Type of the Exception, the message and ideally stacktrace.

Comment: Where is `Add_Row_To_DataGridView_Using_TextBoxes_Load` called?  You're trying to add a row to the table before setting its columns.

Comment: Why do you declare the columns with data type int and then assign string values to them? (this doesn't pertain to the error you're receiving)

Comment: @Christopher `DataRowCollection.Add(object[])` throws this exception when the number of values in the array exceeds the number of columns in the table.

Comment: @Amy, thanks not sure it's the best way to do it, but I was able to move the add column to the button click event before the add row and it worked.

Comment: Somethings is off in `Add_Row_To_DataGridView_Using_TextBoxes_Load`. You create and assign a new DataTable, only to never use it: `DataTable Test = new DataTable();`

Comment: The error message is confusing.  It looks like the Net library is attempting to convert "textBoxAge.text" to an integer (column Age is define as int) and getting two objects. Then giving an error message due to code trying to add five items to a table that only has four columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Add_Row_To_DataGridView_Using_TextBoxes_Load` method is not being executed.

Go to the properties tab of your form, select the Events tab, and put the method name against the `Load` event.

Comment: Renaming the method to `Form1_Load` might also work.